# Java Selenium WebDriver Ram Accumulation

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, ram

I have a java application that create 4 selenium drivers.

WebDrivers are created in the following way

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.addArguments("-headless");
options.addPreference("gfx.webrender.all", false);
options.addPreference("gfx.webrender.enabled", false);
options.addPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);
options.addPreference("layers.acceleration.disabled", true);
options.addPreference("extensions.enabled", false);
options.addPreference("dom.webnotifications.enabled", false);
options.addPreference("media.autoplay.enabled", false);
options.addPreference("dom.ipc.processCount", 1);
options.addPreference("media.peerconnection.enabled", false);
options.addPreference("geo.enabled", false);
WebDriver f = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

I run a periodically task (runnable) created with

`ScheduledExecutorService scheduler1 = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);`

where I add and remove tabs on promise (when a window is closed an `driver.close` is performed and when added the logic add new on the driver where there are fewer tabs)

I run also another periodically task (runnable) to process all tabs driver with a multithreading strategy with a static class variable. I I have to do a foreach `driver.getWindowHandles()` and get html page content to do my logic.

`ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);`

With that approach I can allocate 1 thread per each WebDriver to have more execution time performance and reuse always the same `ExecutorService`.

So in resume, all drivers instance are initialising once and never changed (closed or re-initialised) because the application should run 24/7 .

When application starts and the first two hours the RAM is normally and stable (8GB~10GB) but, slowly and hour after hour, the RAM is increasing and goes close to the limite VPS RAM resource (24GB).

- What could be generating this increase in RAM?
- What I can do to maintain the RAM stable?
- It's a good idea manage some Garbage Collector or JVM heap management
  ?

Regards,